# How to show most popular tags per category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I know how to show the most popular tags on my Wordpress site. But I want to filter that down to a specific category.

Adding a line within the array like 'cat' => 1, doesn't work.

This is the code I'm using to show most popular tags (which works):

```
<ol>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'number' => 5,
    );
    $tags = get_tags( $args );
    foreach( $tags as $tag ){ ?>

         <li><? echo $tag->name ?><br /><? echo $tag->count ?></li>

        <?
    }
?>
</ol>
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: What output you are expecting with category. Do you need category name according to popular tags?
Can you describe your expected output?

Comment: My expected output would be:

In category A - These are the most commonly used tags, 

In category B - These are the most commonly used tags, 

etc...